# Jmeter - I want that all thread group users to access a specific page at the same time

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I have the following scenario in my thread group:

-Home Page.aspx

-Search parts.aspx

-column select

-filter click(user click the filter button, it takes a while to receive the results)

I want that all the thread group users to click the filter button at the same time. How can I acheive this?

Sorry for my poor english.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't ramp-up with value 0 the solution. Of course it will be not the same moment of time (because of different time of responses)  but pretty close to it.

Comment: Yes, they will access Home Page at the same time, but I need the "filter click" to be accessed by all users at the same time.

Comment: You know, it is an interesting question for me. So, take a look at the next couple of links: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745317/jmeter-load-test  2) http://www.2min2code.com/articles/jmeter_intro/sync_timer

Comment: Yes, the Synchronizing Timer is the solution. Thank you!